# How to get specific words in an output of oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, substr

If I send a query like

```
select message_text
from x$dbgalert;
```

Then I get this result below..

```
ORA-1501 signalled during: CREATE DATABASE  "NEWDB"
          ,MAXINSTANCES 1
          ,MAXLOGHISTORY 1
          ,MAXLOGFILES 16
```

But I want to get a specific word which means '`ORA-1501`' in the above result.

What I want is single or several special words that I want to see
in long sentence that includes many words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **SUBSTR** and **INSTR**.

For example, let's say you have 3 rows in your table out of which only 2 rows have the `ORA-` error number.

```
SQL> WITH DATA(str) AS(
  2  SELECT 'ORA-1501 signalled during: CREATE DATABASE  "NEWDB"
  3            ,ORA- 1
  4            ,MAXLOGHISTORY 1
  5            ,MAXLOGFILES 16' FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'ORA-1999 signalled during: DROP DATABASE  "NEWDB"
  7            ,MAXINSTANCES 1
  8            ,MAXLOGHISTORY 1
  9            ,MAXLOGFILES 16' FROM dual UNION ALL
 10  SELECT 'signalled during: DROP DATABASE  "NEWDB"
 11            ,MAXINSTANCES 1
 12            ,MAXLOGHISTORY 1
 13            ,MAXLOGFILES 16' FROM dual
 14  )
 15  SELECT SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, ' ', 1, 1) -1) str
 16  FROM DATA
 17  WHERE instr(str, 'ORA-') > 0;

STR
----------------------------------------------------------------
ORA-1501
ORA-1999

SQL>
```

The `WHERE instr(str, 'ORA-') > 0` i sto filter out those rows which do not have the `ORA-` error number.

**Update** The **WITH** clause is just to build a sample data for the demo. In your actual query you don't need the WITH clause.

You could simply use the query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(message_text, 1, instr(message_text, ' ', 1, 1) -1) message_text
  FROM x$dbgalert
 WHERE instr(message_text, 'ORA-') > 0;
```

Comment: @DoheeKim Explain what?

Comment: please explain me more...

when i excute select message_text from x$dbgalertext;
i get about 3000 rows.
with those rows, i want to get specific words 'ORA-' 
so i can count them.

but i think i cant code  query you said with 3000 rows..

Comment: @DoheeKim The `WITH` clause is just to build a sample data for the demo. In your actual query you don't need the WITH clause. See my update in the answer.

Comment: oh my god.... thanks a lot....
i'm a very new beginner of ORACLE and LINUX..
but i was mad at these things....
thanks alot...
thank u for ur help and thank u for enduring my poor english...

Comment: @DoheeKim No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please go through the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour. If you like an answer, you could upvote it by pressing the up arrow. If you got a correct answer, then you should accept it as answered by clicking the flag that looks like a tick mark. In return, you also get some reputation for accepting an answer. Good luck!